# Serena Dimensions: Find list of items checked out by a specific user

Tags: serena

Is there any way where we can see the list of items that have been checked out by a specific user.

Comment: I'd strongly suspect so. What information does the manual, help, internet search, colleagues, support people have?

Answer (score 0):

Items checked from a project are recorded in the database as a place-holder revision with the next number in sequence. Generally they will appear in the user's pending list (inbox) and will show with state "$TO_BE_DEFINED". Arrange your desktop client views to show state, along with user names and dates (use Customise Views under Tools menu) and you can sort and filter columns to show information you need. You can even add User Filename to the views and you will see exactly where the file was checked out to.
The desktop client is very powerful but needs some customising as the out-of-box standard views are very limited.
With appropriately set privilges a user can inspect other users' inboxes. A team leader could set up some simple reports to show numbers of checked-out files against users. 
There are so may ways to achive this - but I agree it is not obvious to a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Menu, EDIT/FIND/ITEM

On Tab Option:
STATUS=$TO_BE_DEFINED
ORIGINATOR=?user?

Click on tab Find Now

Answer (score 0):

I am still using dimension in 2019. Let me add relevant snapshots as well. I struggled with this let this answer be so no one has to struggle again.

**On Web View**

You can add a column Checked Out By and then use that column to arrange the files accordingly.

1. To add on Web View you can first go to your user preferences as shown below: [image: SEt your User Preferences]
2. You can add the "check out" column by taking it from available columns as shown    below: [image: Add Checkout Column]
3. You should now able to rearrange file in views by clicking on the check out column. The files will arrange first on ascending order of usernames and then by    descending order.

**On Desktop Client**

1. My item list view looks something like the following which doesnt have a "Check out" column in the view. [image: This is my item view without check out column]
2. One way to find out the files check out is using find item. You can find this in Edit -> Find -> Items. Looks something like this.[image: Find Item PopUp Menu]
3. You can fill in the data as follows: Status as $TO_BE_DEFINED and User Name to the user you want to search for. [image: Fill in the status and userid to search for].
4. On Clicking open you will get the results in the items(Find Results) window.

Hope the snapshots helps.